# Aurelia mouseenter support

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to write a simple hover effect for a div element. I see that with Aurelia I can write something like:

```
<div mouseover.bind="myFunc()"></div>
```

Which works just fine however I need a `mouseenter` event and that does not work.

```
<div mouseenter.bind="myFunc()"></div> // does not work
```

Is there any roadmap to add all javascript events? Is there a temporary solution to get similar functionality to a `mouseenter` event instead of `mouseover`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For mouseenter, trying using trigger instead of bind:

```
<div mouseenter.trigger='myFunc()'></div>
```

Mouseenter is a bubbling event and sometimes it doesn't bubble. Using trigger should trigger the non-bubbling event.

I would also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904248/aurelia-delegate-vs-trigger-how-do-you-know-when-to-use-delegate-or-trigger).