# Click and change events in Aurelia framework

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I am using **Aurelia Framework** for my SPA.

I have a change event in the input tag and click event on the "Continue" button with their respective functions as shown in the attached image.

[image]

The row where input and selects has been placed is a template(as separate view and view model), and this template is being composed in a page which have back and continue button.

> **Issue**:

**Case 1:**

Page is loaded with default value of input tag and value is assigned using value.bind, now enter some value in the input tag and click on "Continue" button without losing the focus from input tag.
In this scenario only foo(change.delegate) is getting triggered not foo2(click.delegate)

**Case 2:**

Enter some value in the input tag and lose the focus, again enter some value in the input tag, now click on "Continue" button without losing the focus from input tag, foo2 is executed without any issue.

I am unable to understand this behavior.
I tried using "trigger" in-place of "delegate", even that is not resolving the issue.

Any suggestion or help is appreciated.

Comment: are these specific scenarios that only cause the bug? Meaning, if you just run the app, then click continue, does the click.delegate() fire?

Comment: @James yes I having issue in these scenarios only. Otherwise click.delegate is working as expected.

Comment: I am also facing same Issue , If any one knows Please reply.

Comment: I assume this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904248/aurelia-delegate-vs-trigger-how-do-you-know-when-to-use-delegate-or-trigger

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?